# Neatly printing integers interspersed with spaces

Tags: java, strings, reinventing-the-wheel

The next iteration is [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/90401/neatly-printing-integers-interspersed-with-spaces-follow-up).

I have this small method for printing long integers neatly. For example:

```
neatify(123L)    = "123"
neatify(1234L)   = "1 234"
neatify(12345L)  = "12 345"
.
.
.
```

The code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static String neatify(final long number,
                                 final int groupLength) {
        final String str = Long.toString(number);

        if (groupLength < 1) {
            return str;
        }

        final char[] charArray = str.toCharArray();
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; ++i) {
            if (i != 0 && (charArray.length - i) % groupLength == 0) {
                sb.append(' ');
            }

            sb.append(charArray[i]);
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static String neatify(final long number) {
        return neatify(number, 3);
    }

    public static void main(final String... args) {
        final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (scanner.hasNextLong()) {
            System.out.println(neatify(scanner.nextLong()));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Usability**

- do you really need the `groupLength`? I'm not aware of any number writing scheme where it is fixed, but not 3[*].
- on the other hand, the separator is different in a lot of countries. You can see an example for [thousands separators](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-0169/overview-9/index.html) here (or on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark#Examples_of_use)). For example, Canada uses , Italy uses `.`, the US uses `,`, and Switzerland uses `'`. It might be nice to add that as a parameter instead of hardcoding . You can still use  as a default.
- your code doesn't deal that well with negative numbers. `-123` becomes `- 123`, and `-123456` becomes `- 123 456`. I would not expect a space after the `-`.

<sub>[*] In [India](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark#Digit_grouping) it seems to be written eg as `15,00,000`, which doesn't use 3, but which also isn't a fixed length.</sub>

**Misc**

- if you start your loop at `1` and prepend `sb.append(charArray[0]);`, you can save the `i != 0` check you perform each time.